# Is there a CCC space such that there is a Lindelof subspace which is not CCC?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is there a CCC space that there is a Lindelof subspace which is not CCC?

Recall that a topological space satisfies the countable chain condition (CCC) if each disjoint collection of open sets is countable.

Comment: The Stone-Cech compactification of the integers $\beta \mathbb{N}$ is separable, hence ccc. The remainder $\beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is compact, hence Lindelof, but not ccc, see Engelking, General topology 3.6.18.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a good answer!